# Android: ListView, Last item - Show more

Tags: android, listview

I have an issues, I want to show 20 items in the list. 
But there is a catch: if the user scrolls down to the bottom of the list, there will be an item that says: "Show more items", and when the users click on it, more items will be added to the list.

My question is how is poosible to have a last item, that has a different style and looks different: and does different things,(I think this is used in QuickSearchbox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you [commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s [cwac-endless](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

> cwac-endless: Provides the
>   EndlessAdapter, a wrapper for an
>   existing ListAdapter that adds
>   "endless list" capability. When the
>   user scrolls to the bottom of the
>   list, if there is more data for this
>   list to be retrieved, your code gets
>   invoked in a background thread to
>   fetch the new rows, which then get
>   seamlessly attached to the bottom of
>   the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, do you have any sample, or any pages that can help me out,

Comment: WTF? Macarse already gave you the link to the example: http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless what else could you need?

Comment: It would be much better to describe some possible solution in a code snippet rather than sending someone to some ready solution. Not everyone wants to implement some ready solutions which can be heavy or licensed.

Answer (score 6):

If you still want a clickable item rather than an infinitely scrolling list you can try using [`ListView#addFooterView`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)) to add your "Show more items" item. This lets you add a view as the last item in a list. Make sure you call it **before** calling `setAdapter`.

Comment: thanks a lot, do you know how I can add to the footer a clicklistner.

Comment: addFooterView takes a View. just set the onClickListener on that view.

Answer (score 1):

While commonware has some awesome stuff. His endless lib may not be what you want.  What you probably want is a footer.  On your ListView, *before you set your adapter*, call addFooterView.  Note that if you do that, the adapter you get from ListView.getAdapter will not be the same as what you passed to ListView.setAdapter.

*Edit*
Speaking of commonware, he sells a few books on his site. Buy them. They are the best $40 you will spend on your android education.

Comment: thanks, so you suggest that I should use a footer,, do you have any example on this as well?

Comment: Sure. They talk about it and show an example in the Google I/O 2010 talk on ListView: http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Comment: If you don't want to watch the video (although you should), the example is in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

In the layout below the listview you can put a linear layout with "Clear" and "Get More Results" buttons. Not exactly what you are asking but it can achieve the same result.